# How to auto resize father div based on child (image) size with set ```max-height`` and ```object-fit: cover;```

Tags: html, css

This is just an example code. I don't know how to limit the picture height and still have responsive `#pictureContainer` with `object-fit: cover`. Is there a more simple way to write this code. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#pictureContainer {
  height: auto;
  /*max-height: 100% <-- doesn't work */
  position: relative;
}

.picture {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="pictureContainer">
  <img class="picture" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/brown-two-story-all-american-home-picture-id1158713117?k=20&m=1158713117&s=612x612&w=0&h=s_aoDM4KNoixI9qBLmJOBPMccoWsC11zxuBGGgFRiKY=">
</div>
```

Comment: 100% on the child means 100% of its parent width or height. if set with px,vw,em,rem

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? there is always better ways to do it..

Comment: For my case using different units (vh) solved the case in main project. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive images will automatically adjust to fit the size of the screen.

Add CSS:
If you want the image to scale both up and down on responsiveness, set the CSS width property to 100% and height to auto:

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

for more information visit [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Images</h2>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" class="responsive" width="600" height="400">

</body>
</html>
```